# Swift 5 or up - Image view on pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My images from "2.jpg" to "7.jpg" shows but the first image("1.jpg") on my simulator. what do I need to change?

---

```
var imageFileName = ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg","7.jpg"]


for i in 0 ..< MAX_ARRAY_NUM {
            
            let image = UIImage(named: imageFileName[i])
            
            imageArray.append(image)
         
            lblImageFileName.text = imageFileName[0]
           
            imageView.image = imageArray[0]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nd9Hc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6pX3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change below two lines

```
lblImageFileName.text = imageFileName[0]
           
imageView.image = imageArray[0]
```

to,

```
lblImageFileName.text = imageFileName[i]
           
imageView.image = imageArray[i]
```

as you used variable i to represent index